# php curl proxy options

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to apply a proxy configuration to all curl requests (including Symphony HttpBrowser and Guzzle)? If such a possibility exists, how can this be done?

I tried to register an alias for curl in Centos 7

```
/etc/profile.d/alias.sh:
alias curl="curl --proxy https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx "
```

It only works if I run curl from the console, it doesn’t work for PHP curl

Comment: So as per your approach yes it will only run in shell environment since you have set the alias there and for your question, yes you can set proxy for your Guzzle, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324893/set-proxy-in-guzzle

Comment: No, i need to set proxy for all php curl requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL will honor the environment variables `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `ALL_PROXY` as the default proxy, so you can set them from the shell (Note: This will affect all curl/wget/etc. commands, Check this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1690537/995824):

```
export https_proxy=https://your-proxy-url
```

Or set them in php:

```
putenv('https_proxy=https://your-proxy-url');
```